# Why pdf viewer is not working with iText?

Tags: java, servlets, itext

I´m creating a pdf dynamically using iText 5, the document it's a report which contains some tables.
If i run my code like a java class in my IDE, it does generate my pdf correctly. I want to run the java class as servlet, I made the corresponding changes to make it a servlet class and I used this code to download the pdf, but the screen just turn gray and doesn't show the pdf or an error message, it just stays gray.

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,baos);
        } catch (DocumentException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.open();
        //Tables
        document.close();

        response.setHeader("Expires","0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-checked=0, pre-checked=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        java.io.OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = response.getOutputStream();
            baos.writeTo(os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If I make right click on my browser window, I can download the pdf and open it correctly!

Comment: Please put screenshot of error you are facing.

Comment: I don't have any error message, it just turn the browser's window gray, like if it wants to open the pdf but never completes loading